# How to solve overexposure with hdri lighting

Tags: hdri

I am lighting a scene using an HDRI. Here is my node setup:

[image]

Question is, why is my model still over-exposed, even though I have reduced the HDRI brightness? Thank you.

Comment: That answer comes with a Blend file, try to download that so you can test it

Comment: I did, thank you. Problem is I press shift+A in my own file, and I cannot find the Exposure.World node listed.

Comment: Also, I have reduced the HDRI strength in my file. I can't see the point of reducing the HDRI brightness when it won't reduce the object exposure.

Comment: Could you please upload your packed blend.file on this site https://blend-exchange.com/ and share the download link for us?

Comment: It looks to me that is just a regular value node with the name exposure, used to trigger the exposure using math nodes

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was something with the object normal map; funny, but everything seemed to work out fine when I deleted it. I re-baked it, and re-assigned it. Now the lighting responds as expected. Thanks again, @Evripidis Lalissidis and Emir